# Dell Vostro won't boot with a USB. When try to boot from it, it say "BOOT ERROR"

Tags: ubuntu, dell-vostro

Here's the problem; I'm trying to install Ubuntu:Maverick Meerkat using a USB flash drive on my dell vostro but when I try to boot from it, it say "BOOT ERROR". I used Universal-USB-Installer-1.8.0.8 to create the bootable USB flash drive. Any idea?

I tried the same process on other machines and it works fine.

Comment: Have you tried using *this particular* USB flash drive on other PCs?  BOOT ERROR usually means a problem creating the bootable volume.

Comment: Dude, its a Dell.